# Convert ajax response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, function

I have an JSON that is coming as a response from ajax call

**The object**

```
[
   {
      "name":"Elly",
      "phone":"4345353534",
      "date":"2023-06-20",
      "time":"10:30:00",
      "comment":"Some comment here",
      "timestamp":"2023-06-06 09:16:28",
      "badge": "badge bg-success"
      "color": "green"
   },
   {
      "name":"Peter",
      "phone":"3943476534875",
      "date":"2023-06-20",
      "time":"18:00:00",
      "comment":"No comment",
      "timestamp":"2023-06-06 06:16:28",
      "badge": "badge bg-danger"
      "color": "red"
   }
]
```

**The AJAX Call**

```
$(document).on('click', '#bookings', function() {
    var account = $('#account').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"bookings.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{account:account},
        success:function(data) {
            //the JSON result
            //The function below is placed here
           }
    });
});
```

Then I have this function where I try to create the `events` with the data from the AJAX response. In this example, the AJAX return just 2 records, but they might be any number.

**The function**

```
$(function (e) {
        var calendar = $("#calendar").calendarGC({
            dayBegin: 0,
            prevIcon: '&#x3c;',
            nextIcon: '&#x3e;',
            onPrevMonth: function (e) {
                console.log("prev");
                console.log(e)
            },
            onNextMonth: function (e) {
                console.log("next");
                console.log(e)
            },
            events: [
                {
                    date: new Date("2023-06-07"),
                    eventName: "Holiday",
                    className: "badge bg-danger",
                    onclick(e, data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    dateColor: "red"
                },
                {
                    date: new Date("2023-06-07"),
                    eventName: "Holiday with wife",
                    className: "badge bg-danger",
                    onclick(e, data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    dateColor: "red"
                }
            ],
            onclickDate: function (e, data) {
                console.log(e, data);
            }
        });
    })
```

So, function with the new `events` to become like this

**The expected result**

```
$(function (e) {
        var calendar = $("#calendar").calendarGC({
            dayBegin: 0,
            prevIcon: '&#x3c;',
            nextIcon: '&#x3e;',
            onPrevMonth: function (e) {
                console.log("prev");
                console.log(e)
            },
            onNextMonth: function (e) {
                console.log("next");
                console.log(e)
            },
            events: [
                {
                    date: new Date("2023-06-20"),
                    eventName: "Elly",
                    className: "badge bg-success",
                    onclick(e, data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    dateColor: "green"
                },
                {
                    date: new Date("2023-06-20"),
                    eventName: "Peter",
                    className: "badge bg-danger",
                    onclick(e, data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    dateColor: "red"
                }
            ],
            onclickDate: function (e, data) {
                console.log(e, data);
            }
        });
    })
```

**What I have tried is**

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var array = [];
json.forEach((item) => {
    item = {}
    item ["date"] = new Date('"'+item.date+'"');
    item ["eventName"] = item.name;
    item ["className"] = item.badge;
    item ["dateColor"] = item.color;
    jsonObj.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: We do not need all the fluff around. You basically want to convert `[{ "name":"Elly", "phone":"4345353534", "date":"2023-06-20", "time":"10:30:00", "comment":"Some comment here", "timestamp":"2023-06-06 09:16:28", "badge": "badge bg-success""color": "green"}...]` to `[{ date: new Date("2023-06-20"), eventName: "Elly", className: "badge bg-success", onclick(e, data) { console.log(data); }, dateColor: "green" }, ... ]`  So what did you try? And no jQuery needed here.

Comment: @mplungjan, I have updated the question with something I have tried, that did not work. Obviously wrong. And that's why I asked the question. Also, initially, I added more information, in case the bigger picture was needed, and definitely not to fluff around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You overwrite item each time
2. This is simpler

```js
const data = `[ { "name":"Elly", "phone":"4345353534", "date":"2023-06-20", "time":"10:30:00", "comment":"Some comment here", "timestamp":"2023-06-06 09:16:28", "badge": "badge bg-success", "color": "green" }, { "name":"Peter", "phone":"3943476534875", "date":"2023-06-20", "time":"18:00:00", "comment":"No comment", "timestamp":"2023-06-06 06:16:28", "badge": "badge bg-danger", "color": "red" } ]`;


const obj = $.parseJSON(data);
const array = obj.map((item) => ({

  "date": new Date('"' + item.date + '"'),
  "eventName": item.name,
  "className": item.badge,
  "dateColor": item.color
}));

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean. It works now.